# Find Pitch and Yaw of Face Using Vision Framework

Tags: ios, swift, computer-vision, ios11

Using VNFaceObservation to get the bounding box and landmark information about the face, but have not been able to find where to get the pitch and yaw of the face from the observation.

Have also tried getting pitch and yaw metadata from a CIDetector, but running both the CIDetector and the Vision Framework at the same time is CPU intensive.

```
    let metadataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
    let metaQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "MetaDataSession")
    metadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: metaQueue)
    if captureSession.canAddOutput(metadataOutput) {
        captureSession.addOutput(metadataOutput)
    } else {
        print("Meta data output can not be added.")
    }


    let configurationOptions: [String: AnyObject] = [CIDetectorAccuracy: CIDetectorAccuracyHigh as AnyObject, CIDetectorTracking : true as AnyObject, CIDetectorNumberOfAngles: 11 as AnyObject]
    faceDetector = CIDetector(ofType: CIDetectorTypeFace, context: nil, options: configurationOptions)
```

Is there a way to use the VNFaceObservation data to find the pitch and yaw of the face?

Comment: VNFaceObservation provides Yaw and Roll as of iOS12, but annoyingly no pitch.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I am aware, measures for pitch and yaw aren't provided in CoreImage (I'm unfamiliar with Vision Framework).

It can however be detected using AVFoundation, as demonstrated in the sample project for [this post](https://stijnoomes.com/2016/02/16/detecting-position-and-orientation-of-faces-with-ios-part-1/)

```
func metadataOutput(_ output: AVCaptureMetadataOutput, didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject], from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {

    for metadataObject in metadataObjects as! [AVMetadataFaceObject] {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.avFaceID.text = "face ID: \(metadataObject.faceID)"
            self.avFaceRoll.text = "roll: \(Int(metadataObject.rollAngle))"
            self.avFaceYaw.text = "yaw: \(Int(metadataObject.yawAngle))"
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: OP asked how to get pitch. Getting roll & yaw is trivial with AVFoundation, CoreImage and Vision Framework.

Comment: Pitch seems to be a combination of roll and yaw. https://howthingsfly.si.edu/flight-dynamics/roll-pitch-and-yaw. If obtaining roll and yaw is trivial, seems OP just needs a mathematical function to calculate pitch.

Comment: Pitch is not a combination of roll & yaw. See image here: https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-QiDmXKCYRd0/UhJXzJLugQI/AAAAAAAAGMQ/IOSvrzf24T8/s1600/pyr_face.png -- pitch is an entirely separate measurement across a different axis.

It is indeed possible to use maths to estimate the pitch (and yaw/roll) by projecting the 2D face landmarks into 3D space and then using an approximate model of a human head to solve the Perspective-n-Point problem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perspective-n-Point) using RANSAC or similar, however this is definitely not straightforward!